# Saving text from TextView

Tags: android, save

I'm new in programming on Android. 
What I want is to add to a LinearLayout some TextView by clicking a Button and saving the Text I've inserted in the TextView.

Here's my Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private LinearLayout mLayout;
private EditText mEditText;
private Button mButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("New text");
}

private View.OnClickListener onClick() {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mEditText.getText().toString()));
        }
    };
}

private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText("New text: " + text);
    return textView;
}

public void onDestroy(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}
```

And my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add+"
    />
```

The creation of the TextView works.
So, when I insert text in the top EditText I want that the text is saved "somewhere" for being readable at the opening of the app. Obviously this for every TextView created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use SharedPreferences to store and retrive text, You can use 
the below code to acheive your task,

I made a small changed in your ***createNewTextView*** method,

```
package com.package.name;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private LinearLayout mLayout;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private Button mButton;

    private View.OnClickListener onClick() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mEditText.getText().toString()));
            }
        };
    }

    //Create a field variable
    ArrayList<String> mCreatedText = new ArrayList<String>();

    private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textView.setText("New text: " + text);
        mCreatedText.add(text);
        return textView;
    }

    private void savingText() 
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).edit();
        mEditor.putString("created_text", new Gson().toJson(mCreatedText)).commit();
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getSavedContent()
    {
        ArrayList<String> strArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        try
        {
            String jsonArrayString = mPrefs.getString("created_text","");
            if (!jsonArrayString.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayString);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    strArray.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strArray;
    }

    //Call this method from onCreate()
    private void createSavedTextViews()
    {//nhj
        this.mCreatedText = getSavedContent();
        for(int i = 0; i < this.mCreatedText.size(); i++)
        {
            mLayout.addView(restoreAllTextViews(this.mCreatedText.get(i)));
        }
    }
    private TextView restoreAllTextViews(String text)
    {
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textView.setText("New text: " + text);
        return textView;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        savingText();
    }
    //Here is your new onCreate
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rela);
        mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());
        createSavedTextViews();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get errors: in the savingText method on second line (JSONArray(mCreatedText)) saying "Method call expected". The second on getSavedContent method on new JSONArray(jsonArrayString) saying "Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException", i get also this error on "jArray.getString(i)" on the for loop. How can I resolve?

Comment: Actually, I didn't work on android studio before and these errors are coming only on studio, I resolved the errors and edited the answer...Please check...!
If the exception(org.json.JSONException) is still coming, please write the log of "Json:" in catch body.

Comment: You need this library to resolve the error...!
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm

Comment: Ok, I imported the gson lib in Android Studio. I get two errors: the same in "JSONArray(mCreatedText) saying "Method call expected", putting 'new' in front of JSONArray the error disappear. The second error is on the catch, 'exception.printStackMessage();' saying 'Cannot resolve symbol 'printStackMessage''

Comment: I changed, and add 'new' before JSONArray. I debugged it and tried on my phone but it doesn't works, when I kill the app (through the task manager, swiping it away) and reopen there's no changes, only the button and the edittext.. Meanwhile I thank you!

Comment: The above methods only save and retrieve the strings...! not create the textviews, One more thing you have to call savingText() method from onPause() method in order to save the text

Comment: The creation of the TextViews works. I added the savingText method to onPause but can I retrieve it after the destroying of the app? Have I to add the getSavedContent to onRestart/onResume?

Comment: Brother, I edited the answer again, make your same as I made it...!
Output: It will save texts in the permenent storage on the activity pause and when the activity again created it will automatically created previously saved textviews...! as per your requirement

Comment: I get the same error in "JSONArray jArray = JSONArray(jsonArrayString);" on 'getSavedContent()' method. And another one in the for loop on 'createSavedTextViews()', the second condition must be boolean and in that is an int (this.mCreatedText.size())

Comment: 1: instead of this"JSONArray jArray = JSONArray(jsonArrayString);" use this "JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayString);"
2: instead of this "for(int i = 0; this.mCreatedText.size(); i++)" use this ""for(int i = 0; i < this.mCreatedText.size(); i++)""

Comment: 1. Gets me "Cannot resolve symbol 'jsonArrayString' (on savingText metho), 2. It doesn't gets any errors in the for loop

Comment: Can you give me your MainActivity.java file, I will configure it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0BhYkcl6kmLTGFZeGxlU1AwNDg/view?usp=sharing     you can modify directly in Drive if you want!

Comment: Please check the MainActivity.java from the below link I modified and tested it on Android studio and eclipse both, It works Perfect...! Only set your own setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_id) 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1whmxddx0sywzl/MainActivity.java?dl=0

Comment: I also updated the answer, if the code works fine, you can accept my answer...!

Comment: I think I love you! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know if is possible to add the TextView so the most recent is the top one?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at various [Storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) on Android Developer Guide.

For your scenario. It is probably beneficial to use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) as you can store data in key-value pairs.

To set data in Shared Preferences (in your overriden onClickListener):

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppStorage", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("MyKey",mEditText.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

To get data from Shared Preferences (in your overridden onCreate):

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppStorage", 0);
String data = settings.getString("MyKey", null);
```